# Trouble with Ruby on Rails OS X 1.8.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, macos

I am having trouble with Ruby on Rails on my Mac.  It may have something to do either with my version of xCode or OS X 1.8.4. I say this because I was able to create Ruby on Rails apps in the past.

Here is my problem.  When I run `rails new rubyDemo` to create a new Rails app I get the following error:

```
create  
create  README.rdoc
create  Rakefile
create  config.ru
...
...
Using execjs (2.0.1) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.3) 
Installing json (1.8.0) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/tithos/.bundler/tmp/9865/gems/json-1.8.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/tithos/.bundler/tmp/9865/gems/json- 1.8.0/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing json (1.8.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
```

When I try to run `sudo gem install json -v '1.8.0'`

I get the following error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

I am running:

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]

rails -v
Rails 3.2.13
```

I have no idea what other gems and/or pieces I am missing.

Any help would be great

P.S. sorry for the long post

Comment: Do you have XCode's command line tools installed?  I'd also recommend using [RVM](https://rvm.io/) over the system ruby, if possible.

Comment: Yes I do have xCode's cl tools installed.  do you mean RVN vs Gem?

Comment: I mean RVM to install a ruby that is different from the system ruby and also use it to manage your gems.  It's a great tool for isolating different versions of ruby and installed gems.

Comment: I think this previous SO answer will help out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340486/ruby-on-rails-cant-install-json-gem

Comment: Installing json_pure did not help